# Update the data from the instance SQL its state is unchangued and its not saving its a big Obj

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, backend

```
public string UpdateCateter(string json)
{
    try
    {
        jss.MaxJsonLength = 900000000;
        conexion.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        conexion.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        conexion.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        conexion.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        dynamic newValues = jss.DeserializeObject(json);
        int codigo = Convert.ToInt32(newValues["id"]);
        cateter_mahurka_web data = conexion.cateter_mahurka_web.Find(codigo);
        if (data != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var newValue = newValues[property.Name];
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                        var rspre3 = property.SetValue(data, Convert.ChangeType(newValue,                        property.PropertyType));
                        var rspre1 = conexion.Entry(data).State;
                }
            }
            var rspre = conexion.Entry(data).State;
            var rs = conexion.SaveChanges();
            return jss.Serialize(rs > 0);
        }
        return jss.Serialize("No se encontro ningun registro");
    }
    #region catch...
}
```

I hope u can help me, Im trying to update a database record using Entity Framework. The New Values are being stored into an object called "newValues". Then, it finds a record in the database with the specified "id" value and stores it in the "data" object.

Next, the code loops through each property in the "data" object and compares it to the corresponding property in the "newValues" object. If the property in "newValues" is not null, the code sets the value of the corresponding property in the "data" object to the value in "newValues".

Finally, the code saves the changes to the database by calling the "SaveChanges" method on the database context. The result of this method call is then serialized and returned as a string, indicating whether the update was successful or not.

It is expected that the code would update the database record with the new values provided in the "newValues" object and return a string indicating whether the update was successful or not.

But in the line var rspre = conexion.Entry(data).State; im getting unchanged so it is not updating can u help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am making modifications to a database instance, I am encountering an issue where the changes are not being detected by the system. However, I have found a solution to this problem by adding the following line of code to my implementation:

```
conexion.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

By setting the `State` property of the `Entry` object to `EntityState.Modified`, the system will recognize that the entity has been modified and persist the changes to the database accordingly.